# Trying to render hook Statement, but its not getting render

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to render a useHook statement in React that just display the length of the array and nothing getting render.

**Here is APP.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(['test1', 'test2'])
  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Add Todo</button>
      <button>Clear Completed Todos</button>
      <div>0 left to do</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Here TodoList.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function TodoList(todos) {
    return (
        <div>
            {todos.length}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Here index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Screenshot of what getting render**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s24b.png)

Comment: You forgot to destructure `todos` from the props object.  `TodoList(todos)` >>> `TodoList({ todos })`

Comment: Can you clarify objective of the question?

Comment: Typo, you are not destructuring `todos` from the props object, you just named the props object `todos` instead of `props`. It should be `TodoList({ todos })` instead of `TodoList(todos)`, or `TodoList(props)` and `props.todos.length`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the TodoList Component to this,

```
import React from 'react'

export default function TodoList({todos}) {
    return 
        <div>
            {todos.length}
        </div>
    )
```

or

```
import React from 'react'

export default function TodoList(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.todos.length}
        </div>
    )
```

Just remember you receive props in the form of an object, so you can either de-structure it or use dot notation or bracket notation to access the peops you pass to a component